# Flash loads twice workaround?

Tags: flash, swfobject

While investigating a reported problem with my site loading slowly, I came across an issue where I noticed (via firebug) that my flash file was loading twice.

After a bit of investigation I tracked it down to a [firefox bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=438830) combined with the usage of SWFObject 2.0.

Now, I noticed on the thread that someone mentioned that you can workaround the problem by:

> FYI, if you're a webpage developer then an easy workaround to get your page
>   working with FF3 is to delay accessing any plugins until after your page has
>   fully loaded. An easy way to do this is to schedule your plugin scripting code
>   to run after all pending browser events using window.setTimeout with a timeout
>   of zero.

Honestly, I have no clue what they're saying and am hoping someone can give me a code example that will work.

Do you know of a way to make this work and what the code would look like? Any help would be immensely appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script>
  function loadswf()
  {
     swfobject.registerObject("myobj", "9.0.0");
  }
  function init() 
  {
     window.setTimeout("loadswf()", 0);
  }
</script>
<body onload="init()">

 <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="778" height="198" id="myobj">
    <param name="movie" value="style.swf">
    <param NAME=FlashVars VALUE="url={{stylelist}}">
      <!--[if !IE]>-->
      <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="style.swf" width="778" height="198">
     <param name="flashvars" value="url={{stylelist}}">
    <!--<![endif]-->

    <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
    <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
                    </a>
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    </object>
    <!--<![endif]-->
 </object>
```

Comment: Well, it's different behavior but this loads the flash and then it disappears totally and I"m left with a white screen in my browser page...

Comment: I think we may be doing two different things.  Mine is a thought experiment that involves the code above.  I am not sure what code you are using exactly -- maybe you could include the complete code?

I amended my working code to conform to the setTimeout idea. Also, this might be swfobject 1.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're setting the Cache and Expires headers in the response.  I had a similar issue with a pdf in an object tag, calling the server twice.  Setting the Expires header to be 5 seconds after the current time prevented the second call.
HTH

Comment: it didn't fix the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

This can also be caused by improperly configured [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network)s, where they might be not sending the full content or throwing a 206 or other http error.