# SWF loaded twice in Firefox, workaround needed

Tags: javascript, flash, firefox

I have the same problem as the following stackoverflow question:

- [Flash loads twice workaround?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499949/flash-loads-twice-workaround)

but the provided solution is not working for me (my script runs after the DOM ready and a delay), is there any workaround to fix the [Firefox bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=438830) which is fixed in the bugzilla but still exists?

*update*: I'm using DOM functions to create the `<object>` as [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) does.

Answer (score 0):

Use window as the value of wmode. Transparent and opaque will lead to loading problem in Firefox, even in Firefox 4.

```
<param name="wmode" value="window" />
```

Comment: This does not solve the double loading problem unfortunately. BTW I could not reproduce it in Firefox4 not with `opaque` and not with `transparent` either.